# vba offset with reference to cell

Tags: excel, vba, offset, office-automation

I need to copy a column of data to another column on a different worksheet, pasting values only.  The appropriate paste column is identified in a single cell.  This cell will be changed manually each time the macro is applied.  So one time I might want to copy/paste in the first column, so my identifier cell is 1.  The next time I might input 5 in this cell so that I offset 5 columns to the right to copy/paste data.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the columns in a worksheet using the **Columns** property. You can achieve what I think you're trying to do with code like this.

```
Dim col As Integer

col = SomeSheet.Cells(1,1).Value
FromSheet.Columns(col).copy
ToSheet.Columns(col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Can I use a reference in Cells such as Cells(A6,1)?